# How to allow a widget in Tkinter to span multiple columns going backwards?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am recreating this:

[image]

I'm trying to get the label 'Send to country's leader' to span two columns like in the picture, but going backward.This is my code for it:

```
from tkinter import *

countries = ['Belgium', 'Canada', 'China', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'France', 'Greece',
             'India', 'Italy']

root = Tk()

countryBox = Listbox(root)
countryBox.config(relief=SUNKEN, border=2)
countryBox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')

for x in countries[::-1]:
    countryBox.insert(END, x)

Label(root, text="Send to country's leader:").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nw', columnspan=2)
```

This doesn't work though, since columnspan only works with columns following the one specified. How do I do it for ones before?

Comment: So you're looking to have "Send to country's leader:" span columns 0 and 1, essentially positioning it over top of both the listbox and the stuff on the right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't span backwards. However, you can move the item to the previous column and span forwards. It gives exactly the same result.

In other words, putting a widget in column one and spanning backwards is exactly the same as putting it in column zero and spanning forwards.